# Problems with disk partition

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, system-installation

I have Ubuntu on my notebook and want to install Mint too. I've gone through the installation process but when it is time to partition the disk, I get stuck (it doesn't allow me to create the partitions)

Below an image, where I can't partition the hard disk:

[image]

I need to finish the installation.

Comment: And when you press change?

Comment: @user1133275 no changes...

Comment: Maybe a bug or it's a partition type that it cannot detect? If this is the Mint installer, then reboot and try to use gparted in Ubuntu to create and format the partition. Then reboot again and try to manually select this partition in the Mint installer. It's strange that the partition type is not detected...

Comment: In the existing Ubuntu, install gparted, and then shrink the partition /dev/sda3 (it is un-recognised by this partition editor, but hopefully will be my ubuntu). You may need to un-mount it first (that is another question).

Comment: Do you have an encrypted partition?

Comment: @Fabby it seems so, but it was automatically created by ubuntu installer

Answer (score 1):

You have one encrypted partition on Ubuntu, but as you did not know how you installed it, the *easiest* way to get rid of it is to:

- Boot Ubuntu
- Backup all your data to an external disk in FAT32¹
- Install Mint; wiping the entire disk
- Install Ubuntu
- Restore your backup

<sub>**Note¹**: FAT32 *does not allow* you to encrypt data, so you won't accidentally encrypt it without knowing</sub>

Comment: If you need more help with any of the above steps, let me know and I'll expand the answer.

Comment: thanks. i've tried yesterday and it seems that mint installer recognize ubuntu and it changes the 'normal' installation steps.

Answer (score 0):

You have no free space, and would need to delete partitions before creating partitions, as you are at the maximum number of primary partitions on a disk.

You have a few choices... if the existing partitions are those that you do not want, you can delete them all, and then start over, use the existing ones, or take the large "unknown" partition and use that one.

You may also want to look up some resources on partitioning ubuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/how-to-install-ubuntu/

Comment: Uhmm the existing partitions were created automatically by ubuntu. I dont think they can be removed...

Comment: @number9 The disk has an EFI System Partition, which suggests GPT partitioning. GPT does not have a four partition limit.

Comment: You need no remove; just resize https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd

Comment: @JohanMyréen Ah that is true.. But I would still think he would need to start over after removing or resizing all of the partitions if they are not needed.